# Obfuscation in proguard for inner class

Tags: java, security, serialization, obfuscation, proguard

I have a maven web project and I am obfuscating my code by providing proguard plugin in my **pom.xml**

Now I have a class which contains static inner class
For example:

```
class A {

static class SimpleEntry<K, V> implements Entry<K, V> , Serializable {
}

}
```

Now after obfuscation Serializable interface is removed from obfuscated code for static inner class. I need this Serialiazable interface for clustering as this class is used for writting to session in tomcat. Kindly give me appropriate command to keep this class as well as **Serializable** interface in **proguard**.

Comment: If you need it to be serializable (and stable across versions) then you also make sure it's always renamed the same way, as otherwise deserializing and old serialized form will not work.

Comment: after obfuscation i get the following code                        class A {

static class SimpleEntry<K, V> implements Entry<K, V>{     
}

}  Here serializable interface is removed . But i need to keep it as it is. This is the problem i am facing.

Comment: I'm running into this issue now (assuming you are working with serialization proxy pattern).  Did you figure this out?